# Log4J no appenders could be found

Tags: jsf, log4j

I am developing a Java Web Application using JSF, Spring and Hibernate. I need to setup Log4J. I included necessary libraries and created a simple log4j.properties file.

At Tomcat output it outputs

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I am not experienced in Java Web Application development. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Thank you Ken Chan. Your solution is working and simple.

Comment: How does your properties file look?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default , `log4j.properties` should be placed inside the root of the class path of the web application (i.e inside `\WEB-INF\classes\` of the WAR`) .

In `log4j.properties` ,you should at least set the appender and the logger level for the root logger , for example:

> ```
> #Set root logger 's level and its appender to an appender called CONSOLE which is defined below.
> log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CONSOLE
>
> #Set the behavior of the CONSOLE appender 
> log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
> log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
> log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
> ```